# why are single quotes not visible

Tags: javascript, php

I am making a array from values from databse in PHP then storing it into javascript array. When I alert the array the single quotes are not visible, although when PHP is seen it shows the quotes around values. What’s wrong in my code? It should be `['1','2','3','4']` but it shows `[1,2,3,4]`.

```
<script>
    var values = [
        <?php
            $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("we couldn't connect!");
            mysql_select_db("test_value");
            $rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test") or die(mysql_error());
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
            {
                echo "'".$row['var1']."',";
            }
        ?>
    ];
    window.alert(values);
</script>
```

Comment: Yes very hasty combination :(

Comment: Try to keep it separate, it'll be better and much easy for you

Comment: Its requirment I dont have any choice

Comment: don't do this. just use json_encode() to ensure you're outputting proper json. as is, if you db dies, your mysql error will be inserted into the script block and be a JS syntax error, killing the entire block.

Comment: @phpnet What do you mean by `its requirement`, it's your code, you should  make it better than making a mess. Use `ajax`

Comment: Its in the requiremnet document

Comment: @MarcB json_encode($php) you mean like this ?

Comment: @MarcB your answer worked :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
    var values=[
    <?php
    $conn =mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("we couldn't connect!");
    mysql_select_db("test_value");
    $rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
            echo "\'".$row['var1']."\',";
    }?>
   ];
    window.alert(values);
    </script>
```

Use this , this may help you